# when I must use PUT (or another method) request over POST?

Tags: http, post, http-headers, http-post, put

apart from GET method,
we can make POST implement the request typically as any other http method, so why we should use other methods rather than POST?

```
POST='delete some data from this resource'
```

also we can make the POST idempotence by ignoring the subsequent requests (ignoring that PUT can create a new resource)

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually you could also use only GET and DELETE requests for everything. It's only the question how the backend handles these specific request types.

If you want to follow the rules, then you would usually develop so that you provide conformity to usual standards (PUT for creation, DELETE for deletion) and so on.

Can somehow be compared to response status codes. Of course I could return the response code 200 and 201 for "Unauthorized", as response codes can be defined individually. But that's against every standard and should not be done.

Comment: @xxyy no problem. Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted, if your question has been answered. Appreciate that.